# Accessing the previous and next members of an array element using just a pointer to one element

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

(Adapted from [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693934/efficient-way-to-get-the-sum-of-left-and-right-values-of-an-array-using-just-a).)

Suppose we have an array `int a[n]` and we have a pointer to an element in the middle of the array (i.e. `int *p = &a[y]` with 0 < y < n-1).

If `p` is passed into a function where we don't have direct access to the array, how can I access the elements immediately before and after the given array element so that they can be added together?

For example, if `a` is in scope the sum can be gotten easily like this:

```
int sum = a[y-1] + a[y+1];
```

But in a function where `a` is not in scope:

```
int sum_prev_next(int *p)
{
   ...
}
```

Called like this:

```
sum = sum_prev_next(&a[y]);
```

How can this function access the previous and next elements to return the sum?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the pointer in question does not point to either the first or last element of the array, you can use pointer arithmetic to access the previous and next elements of the array.

```
int sum_prev_next(int *p)
{
   return *(p-1) + *(p+1);
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
int sum_prev_next(int *p)
{
   return p[-1] + p[1];
}
```

The negative array subscript may be unusual, but is well defined in this case.  This can be better explained with a diagram:

```
        p-1
        |   p   p+1
        |   |   |
        v   v   v
  -------------------------
a | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
  -------------------------
```

If `p` points to `a[2]`, then `p[-1]` is the same as `a[1]` and `p[1]` is the same as `a[3]`.

It's important to note that this function has the precondition that `p` does not point to the first or last element of an array.  If it did, then accessing either `p[-1]` or `p[1]` would invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by either creating a pointer to one before the start of the array or by dereferencing a pointer to one past the end of the array (creating a pointer to one past the end is OK).

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of array subscripting (C Standard, 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

this declaration

```
int sum = a[y-1] + a[y+1];
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
int sum = *( a + y - 1 ) + *( a + y + 1 );
```

that in turn can be rewritten like

```
int sum = *( ( a + y ) - 1 ) + *( ( a + y ) + 1 );
```

where the subexpression `a + y` represents the pointer `p` defined like

```
int *p = &a[y];
```

or (that is the same) like

```
int *p = a + y;
```

because according to the standard conversions (C Standard, 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So the declaration can be rewritten like

```
int sum = *( p - 1 ) + *( p + 1 );
```

Now again returning to the first quote from the C Standard we get

```
int sum = p[-1] + p[1];
```

**And vice versa** having the above declaration we can rewrite it like

```
int sum = *( p - 1 ) + *( p + 1 );
```

Taking into account the definition of `p` like

```
int *p = a + y;
```

the declaration can be rewritten like

```
int sum = *( ( a + y ) - 1 ) + *( ( a + y ) + 1 );
```

or

```
int sum = *( a + ( y - 1 ) ) + *( a + ( y + 1 ) );
```

that gives

```
int sum = a[y-1] + a[y+1];
```